# D3 stops plotting points when data source is modified

Tags: javascript, d3.js, plot

I am plotting points on a UK map using D3 off a live data stream. When the data points exceed 10,000 the browser becomes sluggish and the animation is no longer smooth. So I modify the `dataPoints` array to keep only the last 5000 points.

However when I modify the `dataPoints` the first time using `splice()` D3 stops rendering any new points. The old points gradually disappear (due to a transition) but there are no new points. I am not sure what I am doing wrong here.

I have simulated the problem by loading data of a CSV as well storing it in memory and plotting them at a rate of 1 point every 100ms. Once the number of dots goes above 10 I splice to retain the last 5 points. I see the same behaviour. Can someone review the code and let me know what I am doing wrong?

**Setup and the plotting function:**

```
    var width = 960,
        height = 1160;

    var dataPoints = []

    var svg = d3.select("#map").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    var projection = d3.geo.albers()
        .center([0, 55.4])
        .rotate([4.4, 0])
        .parallels([40, 70])
        .scale(5000)
        .translate([width / 2, height / 2]);

    function renderPoints() {
        var points = svg.selectAll("circle")
            .data(dataPoints)

        points.enter()
            .append("circle")
            .attr("cx", function (d) { 
                prj = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]) 
                return prj[0]; 
            })
            .attr("cy", function (d) { 
                prj = projection([d.longitude, d.latitude]) 
                return prj[1]; 
            })
            .attr("r", "4px")
            .attr("fill", "blue")
            .attr("fill-opacity", ".4")
            .transition()
            .delay(5000)
            .attr("r", "0px") 
    }

    /* JavaScript goes here. */
    d3.json("uk.json", function(error, uk) {
        if (error) return console.error(error);
        console.log(uk);

        var subunits = topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits);
        var path = d3.geo.path()
            .projection(projection);

        svg.selectAll(".subunit")
            .data(subunits.features)
            .enter().append("path")
                .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit " + d.id })
                .attr("d", path);

        svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a,b) {return a!== b && a.id !== 'IRL';}))
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "subunit-boundary")
        svg.append("path")
            .datum(topojson.mesh(uk, uk.objects.subunits, function(a,b) {return a=== b && a.id === 'IRL';}))
            .attr("d", path)
            .attr("class", "subunit-boundary IRL")

        svg.selectAll(".place-label")
            .attr("x", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? 6 : -6; })
            .style("text-anchor", function(d) { return d.geometry.coordinates[0] > -1 ? "start": "end"; });

        svg.selectAll(".subunit-label")
            .data(topojson.feature(uk, uk.objects.subunits).features)
            .enter().append("text")
                .attr("class", function(d) { return "subunit-label " + d.id })
                .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + path.centroid(d) + ")"; })
                .attr("dy", ".35em")
                .text(function(d) { return d.properties.name; })

        // function applyProjection(d) {
        //     console.log(d);
        //     prj = projection(d) 
        //     console.log(prj); 
        //     return prj; 
        // }

        lon = -4.6
        lat = 55.45
        dataPoints.push([lon,lat])
        renderPoints() 
    });
```

**Function to cleanup old points**

```
    var cleanupDataPoints = function() {
        num_of_elements = dataPoints.length
        console.log("Pre:" + num_of_elements)
        if(num_of_elements > 10) {
            dataPoints = dataPoints.splice(-5, 5)
        }
        console.log("Post:" + dataPoints.length)
    }
```

**Loading data from CSV and plotting at a throttled rate**

```
    var bufferedData = null
    var ptr = 0
    var renderNext = function() {
        d = bufferedData[ptr]
        console.log(d)
        dataPoints.push(d)
        ptr++;
        renderPoints()
        cleanupDataPoints()
        if(ptr < bufferedData.length)
            setTimeout(renderNext, 100)
    }
    d3.csv('test.csv', function (error, data) {
        bufferedData = data
        console.log(data)
        setTimeout(renderNext, 100)
    })
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the lines

```
points = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataPoints)

    points.enter() (...)
```

d3 maps each element in `dataPoints` (indexed from 0 to 5000) to the `circle` elements (of which there should be 5000 eventually). So from its point of view, there is no `enter`'ing  data: there are enough circles to hold all your points.

To make sure that the same data point is mapped to the same html element after it changed index in its array, you need to use an `id` field of some sort attached to each of your data point, and tell d3 to use this id to map the data to elements, instead of their index.

```
points = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataPoints, function(d){return d.id})
```

If the coordinates are a good identifier for your point, you can directly use:

```
points = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(dataPoints, function(d){return d.longitude+" "+d.latitude})
```

See https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Selections#data for more details.

Comment: Thank you! The issue was that D3 was using the index to identify the circle from the data. Changing it to use key function fixed it.